# array.map returning undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I want the users whose id, name, email, or all three, matches with the query given by user. Everything seems to work fine but the map function .. can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong here...

```js
import {UserModel} from '../user.model';

export class UserFilterService {
  users: UserModel[] = [];
 constructor() {
 }
 searchUser(users: UserModel[], id, name, email): UserModel[] {
  this.users = users;
  let reqUsers;
  if (id !== '' || name !== '' || email !== '') {
   reqUsers = this.searchByAll(id, name, email);
   return reqUsers;
  }
 }
 searchByAll = (id, name, email) => {
   const reqUser: UserModel[] = this.users.map((user) => {
     if (user.getId() === id && user.getName() === name && user.getEmail() === email) {
       return user;
     }
     else if (user.getId() !== id && user.getName() === name && user.getEmail() === email ) {
       return user;
     }
     else if (user.getId() === id && user.getName() === name && user.getEmail() !== email) {
       return user;
     }
     else if (user.getId() === id && user.getName() !== name && user.getEmail() === email) {
       return user;
     }
     else if (user.getId() === id && user. getName() !== name && user.getEmail() !== email) {
       return user;
     }
     else if (user.getId() !== id && user.getName === name && user.getEmail() !== email) {
       return user;
     }
     else if (user.getId() !== id && user.getName() !== name && user.getEmail() === email) {
       return user;
     }
   });
   console.log(reqUser);
   return reqUser;
 }
}
```

Comment: A guess: your code doesn't match any of the `if` conditions. What is that `.map()` supposed to do anyway? You go over the array and either return *the same* element or nothing. Seems more like the job for a `.filter()`

Comment: i am using map function to get the array of users that match the if conditions i provided...  ps- i am new to javascript please be kind.

Comment: `users` might be an empty array

Comment: i have console logged and seen that  users is  not empty and has the objects of type UserModel...

Comment: `map` is not the right function for this. have a look into the `Array.filter` method instead and also reread what `map` should be used for.

Comment: @VLAZ I gave a thought to what you mentioned and it worked .. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

i updated the searchByAll method to

```js
 searchByAll = (id, name, email) => {
   const reqUser: UserModel[] = this.users.filter((user) => user.getId() === id || user.getName() === name || user.getEmail() === email);
   console.log(reqUser);
   return reqUser;
 }
```

and it worked